# How to remove certain lines of a large file (>5G) using linux commands

Tags: linux, awk, sed, file-processing

I have files which are very large (> 5G), and I want to remove some lines by the line numbers **without moving (copy and paste) files**.

I know this command works for a small size file. (my sed command do not recognize -i option)

```
sed "${line}d" file.txt > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file.txt
```

This command takes relatively long time because of the size. I just need to remove the first line and the last line, but also want to know how to remove line number n, for example.

Comment: What's the issue here? Time of this operation or no space on partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way files are stored on standard filesystems (NTFS, EXTFS, ...), you cannot remove parts of a file in-place.

The only thing you can do in-place is

- append to the end of a file (append mode)
- modify data in a file (read-write mode)

Other operations must use a temporary file, or temporary memory to read the file fully and write it back modified.

EDIT: you can also "shrink" a file as read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221869/shrinking-a-file-in-c) using a C program (Linux or Windows would work) so that means that you could remove the last line (but still not the first line or any line in between)

Comment: I see, but what if the line you want to delete is either the first line or the last one? Is there a way to shrink the file on the filesystem by moving the pointers (or equivalent meta information) of the begin or end of the file?

Comment: see my edit. Maybe you could remove the start of the file by moving pointers but you would have to edit the disk blocks (superuser + super-dangerous :))

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `ed` command which is quite similar to sed

```
ed -s file.text
```

you can use the `d` command, `$d` will delete the last line while `1d` will delete the first one, and `wq` will write and exit.

The following command will do everything (delete first and last line, write, and exit)

```
echo -e '1d\n$d\nwq' | ed -s test.txt
```

using `sed` you can use the same commands `sed '1d;$d' test.txt`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a recent Linux, you can remove chunks of the file in any position: https://lwn.net/Articles/415889/

There's a command to remove any part of the file: `fallocate`

See: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/fallocate.1.html

For example: `fallocate -p -o 10G -l 1G qqq`